# I dont know my password and wont let me change it via GRUB

Tags: password, password-recovery

I recently turned off the login password so i would not have to enter my password every time I turn the system on. But now when I try to update or download anything it asks me for my password so I enter my old password and it keeps telling me its wrong when I have only ever had the 1 password and its a simple 1 so I would not forget and considering I have only had UBUNTU installed for two days it is really frustrating. I have also tried resetting it via the GRUB but it wont let me type the new password. 
Please help ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

When using recovery mode from grub, you need to drop to a root shell, then remount the drive with write permissions using this command

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Then you can change the password for your account using the following command (replace username with your username).

```
passwd username
```

Then enter the new password twice, you will not see what you are typing.

Then reboot and login using the new password.

Have a look at [this page on my website](http://fernhilllinuxproject.com/guidesandhowtos/resetpassword.html) for a more detailed guide if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can boot from a live cd and then reset the password from there. Here's a guide on how to do just that:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/